# Remove leading and trailing strings from Shell Variable AT ONCE (using 1 assignment and without functions) in Bash

Tags: bash, shell

There are several operators to trim strings from Shell Variable:

| Operator | Description | `VAR="AAAworldIII"` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `${VAR#pattern` | Remove **shortest** front-anchored pattern | `$ echo ${VAR#A}` `$ AAworldIII` |
| `${VAR%pattern}` | Remove **shortest** rear-anchored pattern | `$ echo ${VAR%I}` `$ AAAworldII` |

So to remove symbols `[` and `]` from string `[BASH]` I need to do 2 assignments in the script:

```bash
$ VAR="[BASH]" # 

$ VAR=${VAR#[} # 1) remove leading [
$ VAR=${VAR%]} # 2) remove trailing ]

$ ... # here I can use the VAR
```

Is there a way to perform steps `1)` and `2)` at once to avoid doing these 2 assignments to the same variable ? Like:

```bash
$ VAR="[BASH]"
$ VAR=some_uknown_operator_to_trim_strings_from_VAR. 
$ ... then my script code uses VAR
```

`PS`: I am looking for a way/operator to remove only leading and trailing characters (strings) **AT ONCE**. I know a way how to trim leading and trailing string using 2 assignment. Trimming symbols can present in the middle of the string contained by `VAR` (Like `VAR="[BA[S]H]"`), they should stay there they are

Comment: Using parameter expansions? No.

Comment: This may do the trick: `var=${var:1:-1}` if you want to remove first and last character of a string at once. But this will remove any characters at those spots.

Comment: @oguzismail could you please explain how?